# Focus issue with Wpf DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, focus, wpfdatagrid, datagridcell

I am using WPFToolKit `DataGrid` to display data; In my use case

1. user clicks on a cell and enters a value (I trap the event and set the focus to the `TextBox`)
2. Presses Enter
3. Value is committed
4. Focus shifts to Next Cell

Now, user can't enter any value in the `TextBox`(in the `DataGridCell`) unless he clicks on the cell. The `TextBox` can be a part of various controls(like `NumericUpDown`, `Calendar` etc.).

This behavior is similar to Excel but I am not able to shift the focus to the Underlying `TextBox` as various other wrapper user controls are there in the `DataGridCell`(something like `DataGridCell` contains `MatrixCellContainer`, which contains `MatrixCell`, which contains `UpDown` Control)

Any pointer will be really helpful.

Update:

I can achieve what I am looking for by handling `DataGridCell_Selected` event like this :

```
private void DataGridCell_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell dataGridCell = 
               sender as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell;

    // ToDo: This is a very bad hack; 
    // should be replaced by some proper technique
    if (dataGridCell != null)
    {
        NumericUpDownBase<int>[] IntUpDownControls = 
            dataGridCell.GetChildrenOfType<NumericUpDownBase<int>>();
        if (IntUpDownControls.Count() != 0)
        {
            IntUpDownControls[0].Focus();
            //Keyboard.Focus(IntUpDownControls[0]);
        }
    else
    {
        NumericUpDownBase<double>[] DblUpDownControls = 
                dataGridCell.GetChildrenOfType<NumericUpDownBase<Double>>();
         if (DblUpDownControls.Count() != 0)
         {
                 DblUpDownControls[0].Focus();
                 //Keyboard.Focus(DblUpDownControls[0]);
          }
    }
    }
 }
```

But I know there will be a better way to achieve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I settled with this -

```
private void HandleCellSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell dataGridCell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (dataGridCell != null)
    {
        TextBox[] textboxcontrols = dataGridCell.GetChildrenOfType<TextBox>();
        if (textboxcontrols.Count() != 0)
        {
            textboxcontrols[0].Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Still looking for a better approach though...

Answer (score 2):

How are you setting Focus to the next cell?

WPF has two versions of focus, Logical Focus and Keyboard Focus. I suspect you are using `myDataGridCell.Focus()`, which only sets Logical Focus.

```
myDataGridCell.Focus();         // Sets Logical Focus
Keyboard.Focus(myDataGridCell); // Sets Keyboard Focus
```

Comment: Actually I am not setting focus anywhere in code, its the default behavior of DataGrid to shift focus on Enter key(I am not sure though). I have also checked this in DataGridCell_Selected event handler and both IsFocused and IsKeyboardFocused for cell comes true.